# How to find conversions between GICS and ICB classifications?

Tags: stock-analysis

not sure if this is the right place to ask but for a personal stock portfolio I'm doing some analysis, and as I am considering stocks from different regions I have a dataset that partially uses GICS and partially ICB sector classifications. Are there any mapping tables available to go between different sectors and subsectors of the two ? Would be a huge help. Thanks